Independency properties in a classification context.
I'm trying to find a minimal set of "natural" properties that can imply higher level independence properties in classification problems.
Let say I've got samples whose classes/labels are $y_i$. I'm trying to classify them from observables/measures $x_i$.
A common independence properties that can be encountered is $p\left(y_1,...,y_N|x_1,...,x_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i|x_i\right)$ but, IMHO, it's quite a strong asumption so I wanted to find more basic hypothesis that can lead to that property.
As a starting point, I'm setting these hypotheses:

the samples' labels are independent: $p\left(y_1,...,y_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i\right)$
the measure distribution for a sample, conditionaly given all the labels, depends only on the given sample's label: $p\left(x_i|y_1,...,y_N\right)=p\left(x_i|y_i\right)$
labels are identically distributed: $p\left(y_i\right)=p\left(y\right)=f\left(y\right)$
measures are identically (conditionaly given the sample's label) distributed: $p\left(x_i|y_i\right)=p\left(x|y\right)=g\left(x,y\right)$

From these hypotheses, I want to derive higher level properties, possibly reaching the one given above.
First of all, are these hypothesis sufficient to prove the measures mutual independence: $p\left(x_1,...,x_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(x_i\right)$?
If it's true, what is the proof, if it's wrong, can a counterexample be provided?
This question will probably have follow-up.

I eventually think that the hypotheses are not sufficient to get mutual independence of the measures.
I built the following counterexample.
Let $h$ be a binary random variable such that $p\left(h=0\right)=p$
Let $y_i$ be binary independent random variables such that $p\left(y_i=0\right)=q$
Let $h$ and $y_i$ be independent also.
Now let $x_i=h+y_i$.
$x_i=0\Leftrightarrow\left(h=0\land y_i=0\right)$
Thus:
$p\left(x_i=0\right)=p\left(h=0,y_i=0\right)=pq$
$p\left(x_1=0,x_2=0\right)=p\left(h=0,y_1=0,y_2=0\right)=pq^2\neq p\left(x_1=0\right)p\left(x_2=0\right)=pqpq$
In plain English, the $x_i$ are interdependent from a hidden random variable, without breaking other assumptions.
